# Print debug information in QT widget form application

Tags: c++, qt

I have widget based qt form application. Trying to print some debug info:

```
qInfo()<<"Txt1 \n" ;
printf("Txt2 \n" );
```

But nothing is printed in `Application Output` console.

I have added `CONFIG += console` to `.pro` file. But no console window appeared.

How to solve simple logging problem?

UPD

This also prints nothing.

```
qDebug()<<"Txt1 \n" ;
```

If I run project in console I can see information from `printf("Txt2 \n" );`

Comment: It worth to run `qmake` after changing project file.

Comment: To show console window you may check `Run in terminal` checkbox in the `Project->Run Settings` tab.

Comment: how to run qmake? Is it in console?

Answer (score 0):

You should use qDebug() to print something

Comment: qDebug() prints nothing. Mor infor in UPD

Comment: Use as qDebug()<< variable      Dont use “”

Answer (score 0):

You should use qDebug () to print .Otherwise you can use

```
fprintf(stdout,"Debug test\n");
```

Comment: qDebug() prints nothing. Mor infor in UPD